# ARCore support for LG Q7+

Tags: android, arcore, lg

Why isn't the LG Q7+ which was released last year, has Android Oreo supported by ARCore but phones like the LG Q6, LG G6 are able to run ut

Answer (score 0):

Below are the supported devices: [Q6 is supported and Q7 is not]

https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

To certify each device, Google check the quality of the camera, motion sensors, and the design architecture to ensure it performs as expected. Also, the device needs to have a powerful enough CPU that integrates with the hardware design to ensure good performance and effective real-time calculations.

https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/concepts

Although Q7 supports Android 8.0, it is based on MediaTek MT6750 SOC and Q6 is of Qualcomm Snapdragon 435 - Therefore, we can not set Q6 as a benchmark/reference for Q7 in terms of working with ArCore.
https://www.gadgetsnow.com/compare-mobile-phones/LG-Q6-vs-LG-Q7

Read through this: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/9n4hx9/v01231_confirmed_ar_devices_megathread/

Possible reason for not being supported has been discussed at, [why ARCore Supported device Limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566166/why-arcore-supported-device-limited) - Please have a look at it.